# Why does device registration not create a device file?

Tags: kernel-modules, devices

I'm currently learning about Linux device drivers and feel as if I have a fundamental misunderstanding on how devices are instantiated in Linux.

Within a Linux module, I can call `alloc_chrdev_region()` to register devices with the kernel. Specifically, this function is

```
int alloc_chrdev_region(dev_t *dev, unsigned int firstminor,
 unsigned int count, char *name);
```

which generates a device number (major / minor) and accepts a device name.

After successful execution, an entry is made in `/proc/devices` with the major number and device type name. However, there are no devices files generated in `/dev`. Instead I must make a `mknod` call to generate the device files.

So my question: why?

This seems unnecessary since I've already specified a device type name and number of devices to be registered with kernel. Why aren't device files automatically created?

Answer (score 0):

`alloc_chrdev_region()` does not create a device node/file. `alloc_chrdev_region()` requests kernel a range of char device number and kernel dynamically choose available major number and returns along with the first minor number.

In order to automatically create a device file, you need to use `device_create()`. To use `device_create()` we need to create a device class using `class_create()` as device nodes are generally associated with class.

Look at [hid-roccat](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/hid/hid-roccat.c) driver in kernel source tree for example usage where `alloc_chrdev_region()` and `device_create()` used in the same driver.

Also this is a simple example. Note that this is not a complete code.

```
#define DRIVER_NAME "mydriver"
#define DRIVER_CLASS "mydriverclass"

static struct cdev my_device;

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = driver_open,
    .release = driver_close,
    .read = driver_read,
    .write = driver_write
};

static int __init ModuleInit(void) {

    /* Allocate a device number */
    alloc_chrdev_region(&my_device_nr, 0, 1, DRIVER_NAME)

    /* Create device class */
    my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DRIVER_CLASS))

    /* create device file */
    device_create(my_class, NULL, my_device_nr, NULL, DRIVER_NAME)

    /* Initialize device file */
    cdev_init(&my_device, &fops);

    /* Regisering device to kernel */
    dev_add(&my_device, my_device_nr, 1)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, interestingly, I cannot reuse the `struct device` I already have -- e.g. a PCI device cannot have a device node directly.

Comment: Imho, this doesn't seem to answer at all the question of _why_ things are this way.